# Could not load file or assembly Castle.Windsor

Tags: wpf, castle-windsor

Hi I try use WindsorContainer in my WPF app. I downloaded dll-s from this site: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx. 
WPF is based on .NET Framework 4.0 so I add

1. Castle.Core and
2. Castle.Windsor   for .NET 4.0.

I my project I refer this Caliburn dll-s:

1. Caliburn.Castle
2. Caliburn.Core
3. Caliburn.PresentationFramework  all for .NET 4.0

and also Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator is for version 2.0.

My code is look like this:

**App.cs**

```
public partial class App : CaliburnApplication
{
    private IWindsorContainer _container;

    public App()
    {
        RegisterComponents();
    }

    protected override IServiceLocator CreateContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        return new WindsorAdapter(_container);
    }

    protected override object CreateRootModel()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected void RegisterComponents()
    {
        _container.Register(Component.For<IShellViewModel>()
                                     .ImplementedBy<ShellViewModel>()
                                     .LifeStyle.Singleton);
    }

}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<am:CaliburnApplication 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:am="clr-namespace:Caliburn.PresentationFramework.ApplicationModel;assembly=Caliburn.PresentationFramework"
    x:Class="Spirit_Messenger.App">
    <am:CaliburnApplication.Resources>
    </am:CaliburnApplication.Resources>
</am:CaliburnApplication>
```

When I try compile my project I get this error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'Castle.Windsor, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

**StakTrace:**

*at Spirit_Messenger.App.CreateContainer()
   at Caliburn.PresentationFramework.ApplicationModel.CaliburnApplication..ctor()
   at Spirit_Messenger.App..ctor() in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Messenger\App.xaml.cs:line 15
   at Spirit_Messenger.App.Main() in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\C#\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Messenger\obj\x86\Release\App.g.cs:line 50
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()*

I am newbie in WPF / IoC-DI where can be problem. I am so confuse. Thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes a pain. Use ILDASM to check the version of the Castle that those other DLLs need and I bet they are different from the ones you have.

I solved my problem by downloading and recompiling the open source code against the version I had.

---

**Using ILDASM to see references of an assembly:**

- Open the DLL with ILDASM
- Extend the tree
- Click on the manifest
- At the top of the page you can see the references. For example here is a snippet of assemblies for FluentNHibernate.DLL:

  // Metadata version: v2.0.50727
  .assembly extern mscorlib
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
    .ver 2:0:0:0
  }
  .assembly extern NHibernate
  {
    .publickeytoken = (AA 95 F2 07 79 8D FD B4 )                         // ....y...
    .ver 3:0:0:2001
  }
  .assembly extern System.Core
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
    .ver 3:5:0:0
  }
  .assembly extern System.Xml
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
    .ver 2:0:0:0
  }
  .assembly extern System.Data
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
    .ver 2:0:0:0
  }
  .assembly extern System
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
    .ver 2:0:0:0
  }
  .assembly extern Iesi.Collections
  {
    .publickeytoken = (AA 95 F2 07 79 8D FD B4 )                         // ....y...
    .ver 1:0:1:0
  }
  .assembly extern System.Configuration
  {
    .publickeytoken = (B0 3F 5F 7F 11 D5 0A 3A )                         // .?_....:
    .ver 2:0:0:0
  }

Comment: Hi I use ildasm on assembly Castle.Widsor.dll and in manifest I see this: // Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}  I am not good in CIL, but I think this assembly is for CLR 4.0. I am right?

Comment: No, ILDASM on other assemblies using windsor. One is using one version, the other another version.

Comment: I use ildasm on Castle.Windsor.dll ! no on other assemblies.

Comment: What is the ILDASM result for Caliburn.Castle, Caliburn.Core, ... ? And what is the version of your current Castle dlls?

Comment: all castle dll are for runtime 4.0, I think problem is on other place

Comment: It is the version of the Castle.core.dll in the list of its dependencies in ILDASM manifest. See my update.

Comment: Thank for help. I don’t solve this problem, so I used MEF instead Windsor Castle.